# Fixes for USB Flash Drive not detecting

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I have a new USB drive that worked once or twice when I plugged it into my computer, but now for some reason it's no longer responding at all. I'm trying to figure out if this is a hardware failure, or if something is wrong with the partitions on the device.

There are no partitions or drives created (/dev/sdc doesn't exist, nor do /dev/sdc1, etc., all the other /dev/sdx devices are ones I know about).

The device doesn't show up in lsusb at all, and I get the following dmesg output when I plug the device in:

```
[  774.628807] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[  774.649696] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5583
[  774.649702] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  774.649706] usb 2-1: Product: Ultra Fit
[  774.649710] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[  774.649713] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 4C530001020504114443
[  774.650996] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  774.651525] scsi host6: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[  775.665963] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Ultra Fit        1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  775.666606] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  775.666862] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 60063744 512-byte logical blocks: (30.8 GB/28.6 GiB)
[  775.667687] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[  775.667691] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  775.667978] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  810.960382] usb 2-1: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[  816.080399] usb 2-1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[  821.456317] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  826.832263] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  827.040180] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 8, error -62
[  827.267718] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  827.475731] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  827.684146] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 8, error -71
[  827.911672] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  828.119670] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  828.324201] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 8, error -71
[  828.551719] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  828.759705] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  828.964256] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 8, error -71
[  829.020270] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 8
[  829.036212] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  829.036219] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[  829.036223] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[  829.036233] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[  829.036455] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[  829.036489] Dev sdc: unable to read RDB block 0
[  829.036541]  sdc: unable to read partition table
[  829.037074] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  829.037079] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[  829.037088] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[  829.037135] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  829.275676] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  829.483693] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  829.692137] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 9, error -71
[  829.923692] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  830.131830] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  830.336307] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 10, error -71
[  830.364244] usb usb2-port1: attempt power cycle
[  831.299693] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  831.507672] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  831.712163] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 11, error -71
[  831.939673] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  832.147693] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  832.352110] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 12, error -71
[  832.380207] usb usb2-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

I've also tried plugging the drive into a Windows machine with no success (Windows tells me the device wasn't recognized). Is there anything else I can try to do to recover the device, or is it completely unrecoverable?

I found [this](https://paulphilippov.com/articles/how-to-fix-device-not-accepting-address-error) link which suggests it might have something to do with hardware over current protection, but I've tried their suggestions of shutting down/waiting for a few minutes, as well as not using the device for a few minutes. The USB ports on my computer work with other drives (even another identical model drive), just this one drive is causing issues.

I have no important data on the drive I want to keep; I just want to avoid having to replace the physical drive.

Comment: Can you reformat it(i.e. `mkfs.ext4`)?

Comment: I don't see any block devices associated with the flash drive (/dev/sdc, etc.), so I'm not sure how I would check?